# Sharing global variable from C++ library to C main program

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

I have `gstdsexample.so`, a C++ library.
Inside, it has two global variables that I'd like to share between the library and the main C program.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
```

Test two scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

```
sharedata.h

#ifndef __SHARE_DATA_H__
#define __SHARE_DATA_H__
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;

#endif /* __SHARE_DATA_H__ */
```

Include `sharedata.h` in `gstdsexample.cpp` and `main.c`.
Compilation OK but I get a segmentation fault when `gstdsexample.cpp` writes data to `*ptr`.

**Scenario 2**

Declare two variables in

```
gstdsexamle.cpp

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
```

Then declare as `extern` in `main.c.`

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
extern int *ptr;
```

Now I have undefined reference errors to the two variables when compiling `main.c`.

Scenario 3:

```
#ifndef __SHARE_DATA_H__
#define __SHARE_DATA_H__
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

extern "C" {
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
}


#endif /* __SHARE_DATA_H__ */
```

Then include `sharedata.h` in `gstdsexample.cpp` and `main.c`.
Compiling for cpp lib is fine.
But compiling for main.c has errors as

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
 extern "C" {
        ^~~
deepstream_app_main.c: In function ‘all_bbox_generated’:
deepstream_app_main.c:98:24: error: ‘mutex’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GMutex’?
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
                        ^~~~~
                        GMutex
deepstream_app_main.c:98:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
deepstream_app_main.c:101:21: error: ‘ptr’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘puts’?
     printf("%d ", *(ptr+x));
```

How to share variables between C++ and C source files?

Comment: The variables need to be in `extern "C" { ... }` blocks if you want to share them with C code.

Comment: I tested extern "C" {} in sharedata.h. Added Scenario 3 in original post. But error compiling main.c. cpp library is fine.

Comment: #ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

Comment: The C compiler is complaining about extern "C" (which is a C++ construct). You need to check for __cplusplus to avoid that. (and just use extern instead)

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
}
#endif /* __SHARE_DATA_H__ */` I did like that but still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a header file... gstdsexamle.h

```
// disable name mangling in C++
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// declare your two vars in the header file as extern. 
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex;
extern int *ptr;


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in gstdsexamle.c

```cpp
#include "gstdsexamle.h"

/* only initialise here */
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
```

in main.c

```cpp
#include "gstdsexamle.h"
```

Thats all you need. mutex & ptr are now available in main.cpp/main.c

Comment: gstdsexample lib is fine. But main.c has undefined errors as `undefined reference to mutex and undefined reference to ptr'

Comment: I also need to declare this in main.c `pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int *ptr;`

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 and scenario 2 are invalid because C++ mangles the names of the C++ identifiers to allow for identifier overloading.

Scenario 3 fails because the `extern "C" { }` constructor is a syntactic construction valid **only in C++** and it is not legal in C.  To be able to do this, you need to parse

```
extern "C" {
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int *ptr;
}
```

to indicate the C++ compiler that they are variables to be compatibilized with C calling schema.

But the C language is not aware of something coming from a different language so in C, those declarations must appear as:

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
extern int *ptr;
```

in the header file, but without the invalid syntax.

An approach has been exposed in anotheer answer, so I will not extend explaining what is said there, just to say that `__cplusplus` macro is defined by the compiler automatically when it is acting as a C++ compiler, so that can be used as in the other answer to allow the header file to share C and C++ declarations.

Comment: I've seen `__cplusplus__` macro referenced in older (25+ years) code, but I think compilers define `__cplusplus` nowadays. Do you know where the `__cplusplus__` with trailing underscores comes from?

Comment: That's a typo, my apologies for that.  Now it's correct.  It's possible that old compilers define it, but today, the standard only talks of the one without trailing underscores.